# Hot Or Not / Facemash algorithm - Why Elo's Rating Algo?

Tags: algorithm

In `the social network` movie i saw Mark used [Elo rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details)

But was Elo rating system necessary ?
can anyone tell me what was the advantage using elo's rating system ?
Can the problem be solved in this way too ?
is there any problem in this algo [written below] ?

**Table Structure**

- Name  *Name of the woman*
- Pic_Name [pk] *Path to the picture*
- Impressions *Number, the images was shown*
- Votes *Number, people selected as hot*

Now we show randomly 2 photos from the database and the hottest woman is selected by Maximum number of `Votes`

*Before voting close/down please write your reason*

Comment: Upvote for you, I wondered this as well but never looked into it.

Comment: I thought for a long time `WHY MARK WAS USING ELO'S RATING SYSTEM` but failed to find any reason, and i think my algo is short,simple, CPU friendly :)

Comment: This question is simply about why is using an Elo system a good idea. The relevant [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_details) page or perhaps a math forum like math.stackexchange are probably more suited than stackoverflow.

Comment: reason see above: "primarily opinion-based..."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ***But was that necessary?***

No, there are several different ways of implement such system.

> ***Can anyone tell me what was the advantage using elo's rating system ?***

The main advantage and the central idea in Elo's system is that if someone with low rating wins over someone with high rating their ratings are updated by a larger number, than if the two had similar rating to start with. This means that the **ratings will converge** fairly quickly.

I don't really see how your approach is a good one. First of all it seems like it depends on how often a pic is randomly selected for potential upvoting. Even if you showed all pics equally many times, the property described above doesn't hold. I.e, if some one wins over a really hot girl, she would still get only a single upvote. This means that your approach wouldn't converge as quickly as Elo's system. In fact, the approach you propose **doesn't converge to some steady rating-values at all**.

Comment: yeah thats a good answer, but comparing 2 girl is not same as predicting the winner ! Then why elo's system for predicting the HOT GIRL ?

Comment: @Sourav: the fact that Zuckerberg is (portrayed as) a misogynist jerk who is trying to evaluate "HOTNESS" is irrelevant - the abstraction that he's used to evaluate this is to say that a player should be higher-ranked if they tend to win in one-one contests with other players. That's how a lot of sports work, players or teams compete one-one. So it turns the "HOTNESS" question into a well-studied problem with well-known answers. Hence, comparing two photos is *exactly* the same as declaring a winner (on that day, with that judge).

Answer (score 13):

Simply counting the number of votes and ranking women by that is not adequate and I can think of two reasons why:

What if a woman is average-looking but by luck her picture get displayed more often? Then she would get more votes and her ranking would rise inappropriately.

What if a woman is average-looking but by luck your website would always compare her to ugly women?  The she would get more votes and her ranking would rise inappropriately.

I don't know much about the Elo rating system but it probably doesn't suffer from problems like this.

Comment: You deserve a +1, but i can tweek my algo to show GIRL with Girls who got same or almost same number of votes,

Answer (score 2):

It's a movie about geeks. Elo is a geeky way to rate competitors on the basis of the results of pairwise contests between them. Its association with chess adds extra geekiness. It's precisely the kind of thing that geeks in movies *should* be doing.

It may have happened that exactly way in real life too, in which case Zuckerberg probably chose Elo because it's a well-known algorithm for doing this, which has been used in practice in several sports. Why go to the effort of inventing a worse algorithm?

Comment: yup you are absolutely right, but dont you think that this simple algo can be changed like this [select 2 woman who have almost same Vote +-5]

Comment: It's true that in order to most efficiently use the Elo system, you shouldn't select pairs of players randomly from the database with uniform distribution. I think what you want is for each competitor to mostly play within a range of their own score that makes the result significantly in doubt, but for everyone (and especially new players) to get occasional opportunities to compete against significantly stronger opponents. Chess does this via open tournaments, for example. I haven't seen the movie, I don't know how the pairs of photos were selected.

Comment: If you mean, can your proposed algorithm be fixed by choosing photos with similar scores, then no it can't. Among the fundamental problems with your algorithm, if some photos have been in the DB longer than others, then they have had more opportunities to be rated and hence tend to have more votes regardless of what *proportion* of comparisons they are winning. Your proposal means that new entries will only be played against other new entries and very weak competitors. Elo is much better, it allows a new, strong player to gain a high rating reasonably quickly.